# ARCore/Depth API: How to get depth of a point of the depth map when I click on it?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

When the depth heat map is displayed in the helloAR project, I would like to be able to know the depth of a defined pixel of the heat map when I click on it. But I don't see how to do that.

Any idea ?

Thanks !